# Checking a WordPress for OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities

Tags: plugin-development, security

I have just made a WordPress plugin and I would like to scan it for [OWASP Top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) vulnerabilities, any resources on how to get started here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://hackertarget.com/vulnerability-scanner/ it has many other testing tools as well, some are free and others paid.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WPScan](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpscan/). It's normally used as a command line scan tool but there's also a wordpress plugin, which can make your life easier.
They have a series of automated scripts that search your website for vulnerabilities and warn you if it finds any. I just don't know how well does it work on plugins, but it's great for overall site vulnerabilities.

It's based on the [WPScan Wordpress Vulnerability Database](https://wpscan.com/).

Comment: Does it actually scan? It sounds like it just compares component versions against a known-compromised database.